# Android - How to set padding for TextView in ListView or ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listview, textview, padding, expandablelistview

I need to set padding for the `TextView` in every row of `ListView` or `ExpandableListView`.
I try to use `android:padding` and child (`paddingLeft`,...) but without any results. How can I do?
Thanks

EDIT:

This is the code of the item of the `ExpandableListView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <TextView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/titleScheda"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:padding="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Setting padding on both layout and `TextView` doesn't work, even if the padding is set in only one of the 2 tags.

EDIT :

Solved. The problem was in the Java code, in the `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` declaration. Using the standard layout it's impossible to customize, but using a custom layout for the expandable content is the solution that allows us to customize anything.

Comment: @Tomer the java code? in the java there isn't any reference to the padding or other. I have only the code which need to populate the ExpandableListView

Comment: i can't think anything else, but i would try investigate by setting different background to layout and the textView, and see the results,  post the results here

Comment: @Tomer change the background color, right?

Comment: yes like this android:background="@android:color/white"

Comment: Done, but no effect. Looking at the java code i noticed that i used android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1 and not my custom layout. The error is there i think, right?

Answer (score 17):

I assume you're adding the items in the listview using a template file (xml layout). If you're not, you have to implement that first.

In that layout file you could do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The LinearLayout will create the padding and wrap around the TextView.

Comment: Doesn't work, i'm using an ExpandableListView. I even try to set android:padding in TextView tag, but without results.

Answer (score 4):

```
for(int i=0; i< listview.getChildCount();i++) 

  listview.getChildAt(i).setPadding(10,10,10,10);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add padding as follows:

```
android:paddingBottom="20pt"
```