# How to add bottom padding to span content of textView within RelativeLayout programmatically

Tags: java, android, textview, spannablestring, spannable

How can padding be added to the bottom of the textview programmatically? I noticed that there is some padding above the text but not below. What can be done in order to add some black padding at the bottom just like at the top? It would make the text view a lot more legible (especially for letters that extend below the baseline i.e. `g` and `y`).

[image]

```
TextView tv1 = v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
String myString = " " + getString(R.string.magnify) + " ";
Spannable spanna = new SpannableString(myString);
spanna.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, myString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spanna.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.yellow)), 0, myString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv2.setText(spanna);
```

Comment: Try `TextView#setLineSpacing()`.

Comment: For add = 0.0f and for mult = 1.0f. Try increasing the add.

Comment: what's textview parent?
Is it Framelayout or linearlayout?

Answer (score -1):

With this custom ReplacementSpan, text is drawn "vertically center"

```
final SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(myString);
stringBuilder.append(spannableString);
stringBuilder.setSpan(new TagSpan(Color.BLACK, Color.MAGENTA), 0, myString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
testTextView.setText(stringBuilder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Class TagSpan

```
public class TagSpan extends ReplacementSpan {
    private RectF mRect;
    private int mBackgroundColor;
    private int mForegroundColor;

    public TagSpan(int backgroundColor, int foregroundColor) {
        this.mRect = new RectF();
        this.mBackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        this.mForegroundColor = foregroundColor;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
        // Background
        mRect.set(x, top, x + paint.measureText(text, start, end), bottom);
        paint.setColor(mBackgroundColor);
        canvas.drawRect(mRect, paint);

        // Text
        paint.setColor(mForegroundColor);
        int xPos = Math.round(x);
        int yPos = (int) (0 + ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((paint.descent() + paint.ascent()) / 2)));
        canvas.drawText(text, start, end, xPos, yPos, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
        return Math.round(paint.measureText(text, start, end));
    }

}
```

[image]

Not exactly answer to "bottom padding" request but solve part of your problem I think.

([Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727343/android-paddings-for-spannable))

Comment: ok I got it, in fact you dont want to add padding to your textView, but to your span content, this is the black aera that you want to increase.

Comment: Yes! That's it.

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198155/adding-a-padding-margin-to-a-spannable

Comment: or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727343/android-paddings-for-spannable

Comment: It not adds bottom padding, but the text is vertically center. So I think it solve part of your problem. I try to add bottom padding, but it means modify span height and I had no success in trying to.

Answer (score -2):

You can use: yourTextView.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);  [Android - How to set padding for TextView in ListView or ExpandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250162/android-how-to-set-padding-for-textview-in-listview-or-expandablelistview)

Or increase the TextviewHeight and centre the text.

Answer (score -2):

**Set RelativeLayout.LayoutParams  for Textview**

```
TextView tv1 = v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
String myString = " " + getString(R.string.magnify) + " ";
Spannable spanna = new SpannableString(myString);
spanna.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, myString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spanna.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.yellow)), 0, myString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv1.setText(spanna);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, tv1.getId());
        tv1.setLayoutParams(params);
```